# Is there a way to plot more labels than 53 bars back?

Tags: pine-script

I am new to plotting labels. To my surprise on the last 53 bars were given labels.

Here is my current script:

```
//@version=4
study("Testing Label Text", overlay=true)

label.new(bar_index, high, textcolor=#ffffff, text="high=" + tostring(high) + "\nclose=" + tostring(close))
```

And here is the result on the chart:

[image]

This isn't helpful to my study.

Is there a way to plot labels on more bars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, there are only about 50 drawing objects (lines, labels) allowed on a chart.
Any number greater than that will automatically be cleaned up by the garbage collector process.
See [garbage collection](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#total-number-of-drawings) explained in the usrman.

[Recently](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/drawings-count-new-parameters-21535/), the user has been given control over the amount of lines or label objects on a chart (with a maximum of 500) through extra parameters in the [study()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_study) function: `max_lines_count` and `max_labels_count`.

```
study("My Script", overlay=true, max_labels_count=100)
```

This new limit is also explained in the [garbage collection](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#total-number-of-drawings) topic.

Btw, if it's your goal to track the value of different variables at each bar, it's better to use `plotchar()` and monitor the values from the data windows. See [How can I plot numeric values so that they do not disrupt the indicator’s scale?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-plot-numeric-values-so-that-they-do-not-disrupt-the-indicators-scale) on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, great answer!