# Why my label text kept on repeating instead of one time per line

Tags: pine-script

I am writing a small script to draw camarilla lines on tradingview chart. But I am not sure why the label text above the line getting repeated. Can anyone help me to fix it?

I followed this [example](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#pivot-points-standard) to see how to draw labels.

My code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © nooby_trader

//@version=4
study("Camarilla 1-6", overlay=true)

previous_day_close = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close[1] )
previous_day_high = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[1])
previous_day_low = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low[1])

// Resistances 
r4 = previous_day_close + (previous_day_high- previous_day_low) * 1.1 / 2
r3 = previous_day_close + (previous_day_high- previous_day_low) * 1.1 / 4
r2 = previous_day_close + (previous_day_high- previous_day_low) * 1.1 / 6
r1 = previous_day_close + (previous_day_high- previous_day_low) * 1.1 / 12

r5 = r4 + 1.168 * (r4 - r3)
r6 = (previous_day_high / previous_day_low) * previous_day_close

label.new(bar_index, r3, text="H3", style=label.style_none)
plot(r3 , title="H3: Go Short", style=plot.style_line, color=color.red, linewidth=1)
label.new(bar_index, r4, text="H4", style=label.style_none)
plot(r4 , title="H4: Long Breakout", style=plot.style_line, color=color.green, linewidth=1)
label.new(bar_index, r5, text="H5", style=label.style_none)
plot(r5 , title="H5: Target 1", style=plot.style_line, color=color.green, linewidth=1)
label.new(bar_index, r6, text="H6", style=label.style_none)
plot(r6 , title="H6: Target 2", style=plot.style_line, color=color.green, linewidth=1)

// Supports 
s4 = previous_day_close - (previous_day_high - previous_day_low) * 1.1 / 2
s3 = previous_day_close - (previous_day_high - previous_day_low) * 1.1 / 4
s2 = previous_day_close - (previous_day_high - previous_day_low) * 1.1 / 6
s1 = previous_day_close - (previous_day_high - previous_day_low) * 1.1 / 12

s5 = s4 - 1.168 * (s3 - s4)
s6 = previous_day_close - (r6 - previous_day_close)

plot(s3 , title="L3: Go Long", style=plot.style_line, color=color.green, linewidth=1)
plot(s4 , title="L4: Short Breakout", style=plot.style_line, color=color.red, linewidth=1)
plot(s5 , title="L5: Target 1", style=plot.style_line, color=color.red, linewidth=1)
plot(s6 , title="L6: Target 2", style=plot.style_line, color=color.red, linewidth=1)
```

It looks like this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your code tries to set a label on every bar.
The Pine garbage collector only keeps the most recent 50 drawing objects on a chart, and deletes the oldest ones. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65272710/is-there-a-way-to-plot-more-labels-than-53-bars-back/65274034#65274034) for details.

This will plot what you're looking for:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © nooby_trader

//@version=4
study("Camarilla 1-6", overlay=true) 

[previous_day_high, previous_day_low, previous_day_close] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [high[1], low[1], close[1]])

previous_day_range = previous_day_high - previous_day_low

// Resistances 
r4 = previous_day_close + (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 2
r3 = previous_day_close + (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 4
r2 = previous_day_close + (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 6
r1 = previous_day_close + (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 12

r5 = r4 + 1.168 * (r4 - r3)
r6 = (previous_day_high / previous_day_low) * previous_day_close

// Supports 
s4 = previous_day_close - (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 2
s3 = previous_day_close - (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 4
s2 = previous_day_close - (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 6
s1 = previous_day_close - (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 12

s5 = s4 - 1.168 * (s3 - s4)
s6 = previous_day_close - (r6 - previous_day_close) 

// Plots
plot(r3 , title="H3: Go Short",       style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.red,   linewidth=1)
plot(r4 , title="H4: Long Breakout",  style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.green, linewidth=1)
plot(r5 , title="H5: Target 1",       style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.green, linewidth=1)
plot(r6 , title="H6: Target 2",       style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.green, linewidth=1)

plot(s3 , title="L3: Go Long",        style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.green, linewidth=1)
plot(s4 , title="L4: Short Breakout", style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.red,   linewidth=1)
plot(s5 , title="L5: Target 1",       style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.red,   linewidth=1)
plot(s6 , title="L6: Target 2",       style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.red,   linewidth=1)

// Labels
if (change(r3))
    label.new(bar_index, r3, text="H3", style=label.style_none)

if (change(r4))
    label.new(bar_index, r4, text="H4", style=label.style_none)

if (change(r5))
    label.new(bar_index, r5, text="H5", style=label.style_none)

if (change(r6))
    label.new(bar_index, r6, text="H6", style=label.style_none)
```

Comment: That `change` is so good catch. Thanks mate.